# Configure Selenium Protractor on Ecplise

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I need Selenium protractor to be installed on Eclipse.

I have eclipse Juno, i installed marketplace as well.

I have installed node.js from its official website (version - 9.7.1)  , installed protractor from command prompt (version - 5.3.0) 
From eclipse it says - Unable to install. Any Ideas.

I tried searching for step by step guide (forgive me) as i am pretty new to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can install protractor on eclipse. Protractor is a Nodejs package, it's not a eclipse plugin.

But you can use/run/interact/refer it from eclipse. Nodejs is a Javascript engine like JDK is the Java engine. Think about you link Jar file to java project, same to Protractor, you can add it as your Nodejs project's dependency. We never call this to be "install xxx on eclipse".

There is Nodejs eclipse plugin:  http://www.nodeclipse.org/, after get this plugin installed, you can config Nodejs like config JDK in eclipse. And add run configuration to run protractor script like you did for run Java script.

Finally, for open-soure/third-party javascript library in Nodejs, we call them Nodejs package offically. Nodejs give a tool to help you to install/manage Nodejs package as your project dependency. The tool is `npm`, like `Maven` for Java.  In most case, we use `npm` to install nodejs package.

For Java project, we can use Manve' pom.xml to manage project dependency. for Nodejs project, we use 'package.json' to do the same thing. After execute `npm install` under project folder, you can find `protractor` and other packages from `<project_folder>\node_modules`